# Redis scan does not iterate all over the set

Tags: redis

I want to divide a large redis set into batches by scanning through it. The cursor becomes 0 after iterating some elements of the set. Assume the set length is 250000, `sscan` paginates about 70000 elements of the set and it comes to end.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try calling `SSCAN` with a large `COUNT` value ?

Comment: Yes, as the set gets larger I increase `count` for that. It seems to be effective but how much increase guarantees the set will be fully iterated?

Comment: Does your collection get updated while doing a `SSCAN` ? `COUNT` parameter solution seems an workaround, and docs say that once the command returns zero, some guarantees are granted: https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Niloct said, There are some conditions which guarantees full iteration:
https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-guarantees

> A full iteration always retrieves all the elements that were present in the collection from the start to the end of a full iteration

When you iterate a large set which has expiration time, you should control the speed of iteration with `count` number. If you pass small number for `count`, the iteration takes much more time and by this, some elements in the set may have been expired, so you miss them.

Comment: Didn't you say that you got a zero return value from the command, and still didn't list all elements ? Don't be illuded by a workaround, count solution seems fragile. The only thing which the docs guarantee is full iteration on zero return value.

Comment: Makes more sense. Is it too costly to encapsulate everything in a `MULTI/EXEC` ? How much time does it take in the whole iteration ?

Comment: sounds interesting! I didn't know it. As I see best practices it seems defining transaction is good when you have many commands. In my case, the number of commands are 3 or 4.